# Is there any way to map two different types (string and array of string) in a single field in C#?

Tags: azure, rest, wcf, scim

First json data coming from request body.

```
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "Replace",
            "path": "displayName",
            "value": "AZGrp333"
        }
    ]
```

Second request body

```
"Operations": [
        {
            "op": "Remove",
            "path": "members",
            "value": [
                {
                    "value": "bb05229b-7813-4f43-bcf9-f7430b5639a8"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

In the value field, I'm getting 2 different types of data (string and array of string). In POST request one is getting de-serialized properly and one is not (showing Bad Request). Is it possible to handle both request using single DTO?

I can't use Newtonsoft JsonConverter as this is not working with DataContractSerializer.

Comment: use object instead of string/string[]

Comment: Object is the base class for all classes and can be converted to value types by boxing and unboxing.

Comment: Yes I already tried object and dynamic fields to capture these data but for plain string it is working and for array it is returning null. Somewhere in stack overflow I found that JsonConverter (Json.NET) can help on this and really it is working but in WCF the default Json serializer is DataContractJsonSerializer which is not working as per my requirement. Now I'm trying to find a solution using which I can replace the WCF default serializer with Json.NET serializer.